# How to add custom fonts in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, fonts, google-fonts

I am using react native **custom fonts** and there is an issue with that. with default the text is on center and when I use a Font then text has not on center.
here is code.

```
<TextInput 
    style={{
       height:40, 
       width:width-10, 
       margin:5, 
       backgroundColor:"#eee",
       borderRadius:5,
       paddingLeft:20,
       fontFamily:FONTS.medium  // if I comment this line then placeholder and text input is on center.
     }}
     placeholder="Search Here"
/>
```

Image with default fonts[image]

[image: image with custom fonts]

note: **I have checked it with multiple fonts and have same issue.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use includeFontPadding attribute, it will remove the default space

```
<Text  style={{
     includeFontPadding: false
   }}>
     Search Here
</Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try if the prop `includeFontPadding` or `lineHeight` remove the spacing.

```
<Text
  style={{
        backgroundColor: 'red', 
        //lineHeight: 92, 
        fontSize: 24,  
        color: '#000000', 
        fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular', 
        includeFontPadding: false}}>
        Search Here
</Text>
```

If this don’t work check the font itself has a spacing. Open the font file *.ttf and check if the the text has a big spacing.